# PWA blank screen (white screen of death) when Internet Connection lost?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA Application (angular) and it works fine.

**Problem is:**

User installing the PWA on Desktop or add to home screen on i and it works fine but after internet connection is lost (or after that click on back button) it show blank page and the remains solution is reinstall PWA. (desktop chrome, iOS get this problem).

Where is the problem? or which part of code I can put here?

Update:

```
{   "index": "/",   "assetGroups": [{
"name": "app",
"installMode": "prefetch",
"resources": {
"files": [
"/*.css",
"/*.js"
]
}   }, {
"name": "assets",
"installMode": "lazy",
"updateMode": "prefetch",
"resources": {
"files": [
"/assets/",
"/profiles/",
"/*.(eot|svg|cur|webp|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
]
}   }] }
```

Comment: Your PWA has passed all of the tests with the Lighthouse tool as a valid PWA? The user is testing on a REQUIRED HTTPS site? The user has never tested your app before (does not have anything old in their cache)?

Comment: @Mathias for example test this pwa for first time and all page is shown and works but suddenly internet goes offline, and for example press back on menu page goes to white and nothing shown.

Comment: @Mathias Lighthouse is good. REQUIRED HTTPS site is ok.

Comment: It could be your Service Worker is not caching everything required to load the page.

Comment: @IanC is there any comment for enable caching for load page? I think cache is enabled. please add more hint?

Comment: I think you can help us by adding the Service Worker file here and any console errors (from the Chrome desktop page).

Comment: @IanC see my updates.

Comment: That does not look like Service Worker code - could you clarify what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to consider an **offline page** with the help of Service worker. So whenever the internet interrupts or is offline, the 
PWA is redirected to the offline page.